# How to update all items in Array in the correct way

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, insert-update, items

Have array of currency rates and after input amount in inputTextField i'm want to update  all items in this array on the amount in this currency  and put that one in the tableView, tried to do that with loop but that's not working correct because that's solution just putted in the table each loop

inputTextField that's name of the text field

```
receivedRates:[Double] = [1.1,1.6,2.0,1.3] // just example of the rates

for i in receivedRates {

    let newValue = Double(i)*Double(Int(inputTextField.text!)!)
    currentAmount.append(newValue)
    receivedRates = currentAmount
}
```

How to update this array without loop or maybe there some other solution for this loop?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want to multply all items in the array with the double value of the text field.

A very suitable way in Swift is `map`

```
var receivedRates = [1.1, 1.6, 2.0, 1.3]

receivedRates = receivedRates.map{ $0 * Double(inputTextField.text!)! }
```

Alternatively you can enumerate the indices and update the values in place

```
receivedRates.indices.forEach{ receivedRates[$0] *= Double(inputTextField.text!)! }
```

I doubt that you really want to convert the text first to `Int` (losing the fractional part) and then to `Double` and of course you should unwrap the optionals safely.

Comment: map is far much faster then for loop

Comment: I want to set them all to zero and it has this error message about "contextual type" and then inserts an underscore in the "fix". Edit: I solved it by specifying "$0 * 0". Kinda weird but okay

Answer (score 6):

You can also extend `MutableCollection` and implement your own mutable map method to transform your array:

```
extension MutableCollection {
    mutating func mutableMap(_ transform: (Element) throws -> Element) rethrows {
        var index = startIndex
        for element in self {
            self[index] = try transform(element)
            formIndex(after: &index)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
var receivedRates = [1.1, 1.6, 2.0, 1.3]
receivedRates.mutableMap { $0 * 2.5 }
print(receivedRates)    // [2.75, 4, 5, 3.25]
```

In your case:

```
if let value = Double(inputTextField.text!) {
    receivedRates.mutableMap { $0 * value }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.map` function

> Loops over a collection and applies the same operation to each element
>   in the collection.

```
receivedRates = receivedRates.map{ $0 * Double(inputTextField.text!)!}
```

Refer: [Higher Order Functions](https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/simple-higher-order-functions-in-swift-3-0-map-filter-reduce-and-flatmap-984fa00b2532)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> let newValue = Double(i)*Double(Int(inputTextField.text!)!)
> ```

The forced unwrappings (`!`) here is a warning flag, and something that is likely to break easily at runtime of your app.

As the `text` property of the `inputTextField` instance is an optional, you should make sure *safely* to unwrap it prior attempting to using it in an *attempted* initialization for a `Double` instance. Moreover, the same holds of the result of the attempted initialization (which is also an optional).

You could achieve this double safe unwrapping logic e.g. using optional binding and the [`flatMap(...)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1540500-flatmap) method of [`Optional`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional); whereafter you may use e.g. `map` to update the values of the `receivedRates` array:

```
var receivedRates = [1.1, 1.6, 2.0, 1.3]

if let rateFactor = inputTextField.text.flatMap(Double.init) {
    receivedRates = receivedRates.map { $0 * rateFactor }
}
```

Or, element mutation in place (I see no reason why not to use a `for .. in` loop here):

```
if let rateFactor = inputTextField.text.flatMap(Double.init) {
    for idx in receivedRates.indices {
        receivedRates[idx] *= rateFactor
    }
}
```

Note that if either the `text` property is `nil` or if the initialization of a `Double` instance by it fails, then the array will not be updated (a case which could handle specifically in an `else` clause to the `if` statement above).

Answer (score 0):

Can use `map` instead of `for-in` loop, which is much faster, but you have to avoid the usage of force unwrapping optionals (`!`) as much as possible, for example as following:

```
func updateRates(_ receivedRates: inout [Double], by text: String?) -> Bool {
    guard text != nil, let inputValue = Double(text!) else { return false }

    receivedRates = receivedRates.map{ $0 * inputValue }
    return true
}
```

**Usage:**

```
    var receivedRates: [Double] = [1.1, 1.6, 2.0, 1.3]
    if updateRates(&receivedRates, by: inputTextField.text) {
        print(receivedRates)
    }
```

Another advantage is that you are using referenced parameters `inout` to update the original `receivedRates` array