# Set a subset of an array to the same value in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

Swift 5, iOS 13

I got this code... which is awful.

```
var horizonalOpacity = [Bool](repeating: false, count: 24)

self.horizonalOpacity[0] = true
self.horizonalOpacity[1] = true
self.horizonalOpacity[2] = true
self.horizonalOpacity[3] = true
self.horizonalOpacity[4] = true
self.horizonalOpacity[5] = true
self.horizonalOpacity[6] = true
self.horizonalOpacity[7] = true
self.horizonalOpacity[8] = true
self.horizonalOpacity[9] = true
self.horizonalOpacity[10] = true
self.horizonalOpacity[11] = true
```

I can replace with this code, which is ok.

```
for loop in 0...11 {
   self.horizonalOpacity[loop] = true
}
```

But can I do better? Can I use map perhaps? or an array slice perhaps?

Comment: I don’t think you can get more concise than that for loop

Comment: I have deleted my answer because an identical solution has been given before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61889091/1187415

Comment: Ok, I voted for that one too :)

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
var horizonalOpacity = [Bool](repeating: true, count: 12) + 
                       [Bool](repeating: false, count: 12)
```

Comment: This is good, but the answer using replacingSubrange was better, but it disappeared :( before I could vote it up?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48369550/2303865

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to use `mapInPlace` extension proposed [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/in-place-map-for-mutablecollection/11111):

```
extension MutableCollection {
    mutating func mapInPlace(_ x: (inout Element) -> ()) {
        for i in indices {
            x(&self[i])
        }
    }
}
```

Then you'd just write:

```
horizonalOpacity.mapInPlace { $0 = true }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48369550/2303865